# JQuery Mobile Website not working on IE9 or Above

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I am new to Javascript. We made a mobile website using `JQuery`, `Backbone`, `RequireJS` and `UnderscoreJS`. To test it we uploaded it over a localhost server. It works fine with `Google Chrome`, `Safari` and others but not with `Windows Phone`.

What can be the probable cause for it.?

`Windows8` on Nokia 720: Websites appears after login, nothing comes up. Just the background loads, no elements and texts.

`Windows 7.8` Nokia 510: Website has no CSS. After login, background color appears but no element and text.

Nothing comes on screen as such.

Please let me know if you didn't get my question.

Comment: Not working is a big term, Please be specific what's not working css or js or anything else, what error did you get?

Comment: try accessing the JQM Demo site on these devices... do you see same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check whether you have included the below tag in the html.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

Hope this helps.